# Displays Data by id on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask all friends here, I hope someone can help me.

I want to display product data that is below the minimum, but there are two tables,

The first table

```
id         | store_name                 
-------------+---------------------------
110        | Griya Antapani
111        | Griya Antapani
112        | Griya Antapani
113        | Griya Sukajadi
114        | Griya Sukajadi
115        | Griya Maleber
116        | Griya Maleber
```

The second table

```
id        | iddetails     | product_name
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------
50        | 110           | YOA Setra IR64 5kg
51        | 110           | YOA Pr Pd. Wangi 5kg
52        | 111           | YOA Setra IR64 5kg
53        | 111           | YOA Pr Pd. Wangi 5kg
54        | 112           | YOA Setra IR64 5kg
55        | 112           | YOA Pr Pd. Wangi 5kg
56        | 113           | YOA Setra IR64 5kg
57        | 113           | YOA Pr Pd. Wangi 5kg
58        | 114           | YOA Setra IR64 5kg
59        | 114           | YOA Pr Pd. Wangi 5kg
60        | 115           | YOA Setra IR64 5kg
61        | 115           | YOA Pr Pd. Wangi 5kg
62        | 116           | YOA Setra IR64 5kg
63        | 116           | YOA Pr Pd. Wangi 5kg
```

Example: I want the data id and nama_toko Griya Antapani just want to appear one only and this is in the first table, for the second table that is the product I want to show all the products whose details are the same as the id nama_toko Griya Antapani in the first table, which I want to show it the most recent data is added, I already use join and use order by store_name then id its desc, but all three emerge because different id in first table and id details in second table. it's also the only one product that comes up, is there any solution for this?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: I want the data id 112 in the first table and the data id 54, 55 on the second table id appear, because there is a relation there, and the data id and store name that previously did not need to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I guess you want like this.

```
SELECT T1.ID,
       T1.store_name,
       T2.ID,
       T2.product_name
FROM 
(
  SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID,store_name
  FROM T1 
  GROUP BY store_name
) AS T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.iddetails
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2e92b/7)

Comment: I really want to display it like that, but it's only 1 store that appears, unfortunately the different stores are not displayed, I have edited the example of his data back, I hope you can help me

Comment: @MochamadNurkhayalKadafi I edit by answer,Wish can help you

Comment: this works, thanks for helping me, thank you very much.

Comment: @MochamadNurkhayalKadafi It's my pleasure :)